# How to make os.system read all the statements

Tags: python, os.system

```
import wikipedia
import os
while True:
    input = raw_input("Ques: ")
    #To get output in a particular language ,
    #This prints the results on spanish
    #wikipedia.set_lang("es")
    wiki = wikipedia.summary(input, sentences = 2).encode('utf-8').strip()
    os.system("say " + wiki)
    print wiki
```

on the output console, it asks for

`Ques:` when I type `Cristiano`

It says `"Cristiano is a Portuguese footballer"`

But when I type anything other than `Cristiano` (Say `Chelsea FC`), it says

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

OR

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 1):

The returning value of `wikipedia.summary()` may contain characters that the shell interprets with special meaning. You can escape such characters with `shlex.quote()`:

```
import wikipedia
import os
import shlex
while True:
    input = raw_input("Ques: ")
    #To get output in a particular language ,
    #This prints the results on spanish
    #wikipedia.set_lang("es")
    wiki = wikipedia.summary(input, sentences = 2).encode('utf-8').strip()
    os.system("say " + shlex.quote(wiki))
    print wiki
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7 , I am getting this error 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'quote'

Comment: But if I use pipes , It works . import pipes 
os.system("say " + pipes.quote(wiki))

Comment: Yes, `pipes` for 2.7 has been deprecated in 3.x, where it is replaced by `shlex`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't work with `wikipedia` third-party before. But when I try your code and I found that I just need to **delete `.encode('utf-8')`**. And it's work for me.

**`wiki = wikipedia.summary(i, sentences=2).strip()`**

```
 import wikipedia
 import os
 while True:
    i = input("Ques: ")
    #To get output in a particular language ,
    #This prints the results on spanish
    #wikipedia.set_lang("es")
    wiki = wikipedia.summary(i, sentences=2).strip()
    os.system("say "+ wiki)
    print(wiki)
```

Result: `Chelsea Football Club is a professional football club in London, England, that competes in the Premier League. Founded in 1905, the club's home ground since then has been Stamford Bridge.Chelsea won the First Division title in 1955, ...`.

**Or** you can you use another third-party like *pyttsx3*: `pip install pyttsx3`.

And the code will be like this:

```
   import wikipedia
   import pyttsx3

   engine = pyttsx3.init()

   while True:
    i = input("Ques: ")
    wiki = wikipedia.summary(i, sentences=2).strip()
    # os.system("say "+ wiki)
    print(wiki)

    engine.say(wiki)
    engine.runAndWait()`
```

I hope it can help.

Comment: I am getting the output but the speech is not made by the OS . It again says 
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @krishnakumar I think maybe it also depends on python version, I'm using `python 3.5.2`. 

And if you want to speak it out, I edited the post.